# How to pretty print the output from DB to a JSON file using Spring batch?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-batch

I have implemented the `JsonFileItemWriter` to write the data from database to a file as a json structure. However I don't see an option to pretty print the json.

**The following example shows how to define a JsonFileItemWriter:**

```
@Bean
public JsonFileItemWriter<Trade> jsonFileItemWriter() {
   return new JsonFileItemWriterBuilder<Trade>()
                 .jsonObjectMarshaller(new JacksonJsonObjectMarshaller<>())
                 .resource(new ClassPathResource("trades.json"))
                 .name("tradeJsonFileItemWriter")
                 .build();
}
```

**Actual Output:**

```
[
{name="abc", id="1"},
{name="abcd", id="2"}
]
```

**Expected:**

```
[
  {
    name="abc", 
    id="1"
  },
  {
    name="abcd", 
    id="2"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As we don't have any option to add the pretty print to the default `JacksonJsonObjectMarshaller` I have implemented my own `JacksonJsonObjectMarshaller` and added the pretty print option to it.

```
  public String marshal(T item) {
    try {
      ObjectWriter objectWriter = objectMapper.writer().withDefaultPrettyPrinter();
      return objectWriter.writeValueAsString(item);
    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
      throw new ItemStreamException("Unable to marshal object " + item + " to Json", e);
    }
  }
```

Another Option:

Create new ObjectMapper with the pretty print option and then pass the same to `JacksonJsonObjectMarshaller`.

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper().enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
return new JsonFileItemWriterBuilder<Trade>()
                     .jsonObjectMarshaller(new JacksonJsonObjectMarshaller<>(objectMapper))
                     .resource(new ClassPathResource("trades.json"))
                     .name("tradeJsonFileItemWriter")
                     .build();
```

Comment: No need to create your own JacksonJsonObjectMarshaller, you can use the provided one and pass a custom `ObjectMapper` (that is configured to pretrry print the output) in the constructor.